# Why does getBody().doOnNext() get called different times?

Tags: spring-webflux, reactor-netty

I implemented filter and request decorator to log request body in Webflux.
(I referred this post. https://piotrminkowski.com/2019/10/15/reactive-logging-with-spring-webflux-and-logstash/)

Most of cases, it works fine, but I found out sometimes doOnNext() get called 2 times, so the request body gets logged as 2 split logs. I added log() in the code and the log of flux looks differently like below.

0. logging code

```
   @Override
   public Flux<DataBuffer> getBody() {
      ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      return super.getBody().doOnNext(dataBuffer -> {
         try {
            Channels.newChannel(baos).write(dataBuffer.asByteBuffer().asReadOnlyBuffer());
            String body = IOUtils.toString(baos.toByteArray(), "UTF-8");
            LOGGER.info("Request: method={}, uri={}, payload={}, audit={}", getDelegate().getMethod(),
                  getDelegate().getPath(), body, value("audit", true));
         } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         } finally {
            try {
               baos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
      });
   }
```

1. expected case

```
[ctor-http-nio-5] reactor.Flux.Map.25                      : onSubscribe(FluxMap.MapSubscriber)
[ctor-http-nio-5] reactor.Flux.Map.25                      : request(unbounded)
[ctor-http-nio-5] reactor.Flux.Map.25                      : onNext(PooledSlicedByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 396, cap: 396/396, unwrapped: PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 658, widx: 658, cap: 2048)))
[ctor-http-nio-5] reactor.Flux.Map.25                      : onComplete()
```

2. unexpected case

```
[ctor-http-nio-5] reactor.Flux.Map.20                      : onSubscribe(FluxMap.MapSubscriber)
[ctor-http-nio-5] reactor.Flux.Map.20                      : request(unbounded)
[ctor-http-nio-5] reactor.Flux.Map.19                      : onNext(PooledSlicedByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 122, cap: 122/122, unwrapped: PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 384, widx: 384, cap: 384)))
[ctor-http-nio-5] reactor.Flux.Map.19                      : onNext(PooledSlicedByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 274, cap: 274/274, unwrapped: PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 274, widx: 274, cap: 448)))
[ctor-http-nio-5] reactor.Flux.Map.19                      : onComplete()
```

Could anyone please explain why this happens?

Comment: What data are you sending, the buffer could be full and it is chunking

Comment: @Toerktumlare It's just a small json string, a few hundreds bytes.